# setting up scala for jupyter notebook

Tags: scala, configuration, jupyter, environment

Hi i'm running trouble setting up scala on jupyter notebook.
I already created the environment on conda's command prompt but unlike python or julia environments i prepared before , this one is returning "Intitializing Scala interpreter ...".
reading logs i think there's an interpreter finder called when this happens and it's failing to find interpreter.
Ideas on how to circumvent this issue ?
tyvm
[result when executing simple scala code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb54B.png)

```
 val x:Int =1 
 val y:Int =7 
 var z:Int = x+y
```

> Intitializing Scala interpreter ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have scala exe in your path? Check if you can just run the scala interpreter from the command prompt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).